# How to include angular web component in angular project

Tags: angular, web-component

I want to use an angular web component in my angular app, so for example I try to include an angular component like [snakecomponent](https://itnext.io/angular-9-snake-web-component-96f61e63b158) in my angular project but for some reason, it works only in dev, when I use it in production I have a blank page and I don't see even the app component HTML, and I don't have any error in console.

If I try to use http-server to see my project in production I see this error the first time I load it:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry':
> the name "ng-snake" has already been used with this registry

if you want to see the code is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/snake-components?file=src/index.html
(I know probably in stackblitz script is not loaded right, but the code is the same I have)

Comment: the error is different on stackblitz. for some reason stb doesn't load your scripts defined in html. if you add ts import there `import 'https://gogakoreli.github.io/angular-snake-web-component/snake-web-component.js';` everything will be working. how do you import your script in your app?

Comment: in the index like I do in stackblitz

Comment: The error says you are defining ``ng-snake`` **again**. Are you loading code twice? Should still work as ``ng-snake`` was already defined.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, where? you can see the code

Comment: Alas, I can only interpret the error for you. *Diving* into your code is something you have to do yourself (read: I loved Angular 1; I stopped with everything Angular when they said it was version 2.0 and they made it a new language)